# Not able to access camera even though proper permissions are declared in manifest file

Tags: android, android-camera, android-permissions

I wrote a code to access camera to take photos for profile page. Code is as given below:

```
case R.id.textViewTakePhoto:
                try {
                    Utility.showPopupMenuWindow(mContext, false, mPopupWindow);

                    int camera = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

                    if (camera != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Intent intent= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    }
                    else{
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext,
                                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                9);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Can't access camera" + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   

                break;
```

In my manifest file, I've added the following code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<!--for camera purposes-->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
```

`compileSdkVersion` is 25. When I try to run the application, it throws the error:

```
Can't access cameraPermission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE cmp=com.google.android.GoogleCamera/com.android.camera.activity.CaptureActivity } from ProcessRecord{1d685bf 17561:com.dell.engage/u0a215} (pid=17561, uid=10215) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
```

How can I fix this

Comment: give permission on run time.

Comment: A user can permanently deny access to a certain application. Go to the app settings -> permissions and make sure that the camera permissions are enabled. Also, you may want to show the user a message informing why it's important to give your app this permissions if it crucial for it.

Comment: from your code i can see that you are only checking camera permission is granted or not, and not asking the user to allow permission to use camera.

Answer (score 1):

You have used wrong code while checking permission is granted or not. See below code :

```
   if (camera != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
              ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext,
              new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},9); 
   }
   else{
              Intent intent= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
               startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   }
```

Comment: This code won't work because minSdk in my code is 16. Your code is at minSdk 23

Comment: Welcome. Glad to help you.
Can you share what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

> in your manifest

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
```

> Java code

in your onClick methode :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_CAMERA);
```

and then implement `onActivityResult`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            final Bitmap btm = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
            mImgView.setImageBitmap(btm);


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "no image selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You havent declared any permissions. Try something like this:

```
if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(YourActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                                }else {
                                    String[] permissionRequest = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
                                    requestPermissions(permissionRequest, 8675309);
                                }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(requestCode == 8675309){
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
  } else {
                Toast.makeText(EnterDataView.this, "Cannot take photo without permission.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Also check if you have given CAMERA permission in your manifest file like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
@OnClick(R.id.button_camera)
    void onClickCamera() {
        mPresenter.openCamera(this);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.gallery_button)
    void onClickGallery() {
        mPresenter.openGallery(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mPresenter.startEditing(requestCode, resultCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void startGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, GalleryActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void startCamera(Uri uri) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CAMERA);
        }
    }
```